# Sql 05 express management studio versus standard

Tags: sql-server, ssms

What are the differences between the free sql express 05 management studio and the licensed version?

Answer (score 1):

Management Studio Express cannot manage the following:

- SQL Server Analysis Services
- Integration Services
- Notification Services
- Reporting Services
- SQL Server Agent
- SQL Server 2005 Mobile Edition

( from [this page.](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?familyid=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en) Look at the **Note** in the **Overview** section. )

These are all features that are not supported by SQL Server Express.

Also note that the full version of SQL Management Studio is included with SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

See the "SQL Server 2005 Features Comparison" at http://www.microsoft.com/sql/prodinfo/features/compare-features.mspx

Comment: This link points to a table describing the differences between SQL Server and SQL Server Express - the database itself, not the Management Studio that the question is regarding